# IMAP: Fetch message text and specific headers at once?

Tags: imap

I've read through the [RFC 3501-section 6.5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501.html#section-6.4.5) spec but it isn't clear to me on how to structure the `BODY` to retrieve two sections at once. Individually `BODY[1]` and `BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT TO FROM CC BCC)]` are what I want but I would like to do this as a single `FETCH`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(BODY[1] BODY[HEADER.FIELDS (SUBJECT TO FROM CC BCC)]) will do it in a single FETCH.

Comment: yes thank you, I was neglecting the surrounding `( )`s

Comment: THIS, is pure gold.